# Wall switch doesn't work on fireplace

Tags: switch, gas, fireplace

Our gas fireplace has the panel underneath for ignition, gas level, and pilot/on/off. We can fully operate the fireplace from here regardless of the wall switch. I'd like to leave the one knob on `on` and just use the switch on the wall, but the switch doesn't turn the gas off. What could be wrong or what am I doing wrong that is preventing me from using the wall switch for operation? There is also a key in the wall for the gas supply.

Comment: This is a fireplace that worked correctly at some point? Or is it a new install? Excepting  bone-head checks like "Are you sure that the switch that you're toggling actually operates the fireplace?," you should turn its gas off with the key and get a technician to look at it.

Comment: Gas fireplaces are installed in various control configurations. For example, on my gas fireplace the wall switch only provides the master power for the thermostatically controlled fan. Your wall switch, like mine, may not be set up to light or shut down the burners.

Answer (score 1):

I have two gas fireplaces.  One can be turned on and off from the wall switch.  The other one does not have this feature.  The wall switch only turns on/off the fan.

Some models have kits that can change it over. If the supplier is still around, you can ask them if they have a kit.  Note that one supplier will not alter another suppliers fireplace, even if they have the parts that could make it work.

If you do manage to find the kit, in NZ anyway, a gasfitter must install it.